# Matching string separated by - using regex

Tags: c#, regex

Regex is not my favorite thing, but it certainly has it's uses. Right now I'm trying to match a string consisting of this.

```
[video-{service}-{id}]
```

An example of such a string:

> [video-123abC-zxv9.89]

In the example above I would like to get the "service" 123abC and the "id" zxv9.89.

So far this is what I've got. Probably overcompliacated..

```
var regexPattern = @"\[video-(?<id1>[^]]+)(-(?<id2>[^]]+))?\]";
var ids = Regex.Matches(text, regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => new VideoReplaceItem()
    {
        Tag = m.Value,
        Id = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Groups["id1"].Value) == false ? m.Groups["id1"].Value : "",
        Service = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Groups["id2"].Value) == false ? m.Groups["id2"].Value : "",
    }).ToList();
```

This does not work and puts all the charachters after '[video-' into into Id variable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Change `(?<id1>[^]]+)` to `(?<id1>[^]-]+)`, this way you exclude the `-` from the character class and you avoid to use a lazy quantifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third part seems to be optional. The `[^]]+` is actually matching the `-` symbol, and to fix the expression, you either need to make the first `[^]]+` lazy (`[^]]+?`) or add a hyphen to the negated character class.

Use

```
\[video-(?<id1>[^]-]+)(-(?<id2>[^]-]+))?]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ylj6Jt/1)

Or with the lazy character class:

```
\[video-(?<id1>[^]]+?)(-(?<id2>[^]]+))?]
                    ^
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/ylj6Jt/2).

Since you are using named groups, you may compile the regex object with `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` option to make the regex engine treat all numbered capturing groups as non-capturing ones (so as not to add `?:` after the `(` that defines the optional `(-(?<id2>[^]-]+))?` group).

Comment: To pass two options to the regex constructor, use `|`: `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\[video-(?<service>[^]]+?)(-(?<id>[^]]+))?\]
```

The "?" in the service group makes the expression before it "lazy" (meaning it matches the fewest possible characters to satisfy the overall expression).

I would recommend Regexstorm.net for .NET regex testing: http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: While it is a good idea in general to use the relevant Web regex tester, this expression will work the same way both in PCRE and .NET, so to showcase how the regex works, regex101 is OK to use.

Comment: Wiktor, good point. This is Perl compatible syntax. But not all .NET compatible regex is. I prefer to test regex in a .NET tester to confirm as a final sanity check (oftentimes it's another developer's regex I'm working with). Regex101 really is a far superior tool :)

Comment: Here is a sample code of the answer: [rextester.com/XPCP71913](http://rextester.com/XPCP71913)

Comment: @JohnBindel: I  think  that online regex testers cannot serve a proof the solution works, only testing in the target environment is such a proof. Online testers often have bugs, or not that transparent for testing (try testing RightToLeft option at RegexStorm with a long string :)). So, http://rextester.com/XPCP71913 is a good proof.